# Is it possible to compile Java into machine code? (Not bytecode)

Tags: java

Can you have Java compiled straight into machine code?

I want to do this so I have control over what platforms it's used on, and don't know C,C++ etc.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears that the [GNU Compiler for Java](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) can convert Java source code into either Java bytecode or machine code. It can also convert existing Java bytecode into machine code. However, the last news is from 2009, so I'm not sure how current it is and if it can handle the latest features of the Java language.

Comment: If Java bytecode hasn't changed since 2009, this should still work without developers waving "Hey! I'm still here" flags over the software.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe Java 7 introduced some new language concepts, so it might fail at converting source files into machine code. If the bytecode has also changed with these new features, then that would fail as well

Comment: Excelsior JET seems to be still active (commercial). There was Fujitsu TowerJ, but that seems to have died a decade ago and was pretty pointless back then.

Comment: I'm using java 6 so java 7 is no problem in my case

Comment: Java 8 can emit new bytecodes that will break the GNU compiler, whilst Java 7 (the language) couldn't, you could get say JRuby to generate an invokedynamic, which also would have broken things..

Comment: The website of GCJ says it hadn't fully support even Java 1.5. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040404/1257384

Answer (score 13):

Not quite directly answering the OP, but an perhaps an interesting aside.  Java can be run in three modes:

1. Mixed (default) - A combination of Interpreted and Machine compiled code (machine compiled == compiled by JIT at runtime)
2. With `-Xint` flag - Interpreted - Byte code only
3. With `-Xcomp` flag - Compiled - machine compiled

Comment: @Martjin Are this for the HotSpot? By chance do you have reference for the `-Xcomp` because I could not find that one in the JDK 7 documentation or the HotSpot options documentation and not sure if you have some hidden mailing list secrets that we, the mere mortals, are not aware of :-)

Comment: It is a deliberately hidden option yes :-).  There are various openjdk (openjdk.java.net) mailing lists you can glean this sort of info from - or read the source code :-)

Comment: Please note that according to my tests, -Xcomp can have poorer performance (by a factor of two) in some instances.

Comment: Well yeah.  Just in time optimizations are hard to do when the JIT isn't even running.  Can have != will have.

Comment: ummm so these are options to `javac`? when using the -Xcomp does it by default output a single binary file?

Comment: This is an option to `java`, that is how the JIT compiler operates during runtime

Answer (score 8):

It might be better to detect the operating system using [System.getProperty(“os.name”)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/).  That would let you choose to support more than one OS, but exclude others.

Comment: Is there a way this could be fooled/gamed?

Comment: @Frustrated, probably, but I was assuming his intent was to keep from officially supporting operating systems he hasn't tested.  It doesn't make sense otherwise to intentionally disable portability you get essentially free.

Comment: It also might be that he wants to tie the program to specific hardware in an OS-independent sort of way.

Comment: You can force "os.name" system property by using special arguments for JVM: `java -Dos.name=MacOS`.

Answer (score 4):

It is now: GraalVM allows you to compile your programs ahead-of-time into a native executable. Take a look at **native-image** feature:

- Summary
  https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#native-images
- Demos: Native images for faster startup
  https://www.graalvm.org/docs/examples/native-list-dir/
- Detailed: 'Ahead-of-time Compilation'
  https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/aot-compilation/

Related question: 'Can I compile Java to native code?'
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991799/can-i-compile-java-to-native-code/50555050#50555050

---

P. S. GCJ isn’t maintained anymore.
Source: 'The Deletion of gcj' http://tromey.com/blog/?p=911